# I'm trying to push to public repository I've just created but it's failing

Tags: git, github

I'm using the anaconda prompt to clone my public git repo I've just created.

No problem cloning and committing a test file locally, but when I try and push the changes I get the following:

```
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 255)
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Never seen this before but fine. I enter my username and then it gives the following:

```
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 255)
error: cannot spawn stty: No such file or directory
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com':
```

I then attempt to enter my password but then it doesn't let me type! The cursor is there but when I type no words appear. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When asking for sensitive information, terminal applications tend not to show what you're typing -- this way they don't give away the length of your password. Don't worry, even if it's not showing up, it's still registering what you're typing.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'll give it a go!